# How can I use a bat file to mass-copy files from child-dir to root?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

How can I use windows bat or powershell to mass-copy files from child-dirs to the root/main directory? eg,

c:\dir\1
c:\dir\2
c:\dir\3
etc

to
c:\dir

without having to copy-paste them all manually.

Comment: um, er, what does your BAT/CMD question have to do with powershell? i recommend removing that tag since you appear to NOT want a PoSh solution.

Answer (score 0):

- In a batch file:

  `for /d %%d in ("C:\Dir\*") do for %%f in ("%%d\*") do copy "%%f" "%%d\.."`
- Interactively:

  `for /d %d in ("C:\Dir\*") do for %f in ("%d\*") do copy "%f" "%d\.."`

Hint: `for /d` iterates over directories. Use `for /?` for more details.

Comment: @Compo: Inefficient how? And wildcards also match directories, the question wants only the files.

Comment: Copying each file one by one seems inefficient, perhaps using `copy` with the directory name would be better, e.g. `@CD /D "C:\Dir" 2>NUL&&For /D %%A In (*)Do @Copy "%%A"` and obviously if the batch/current directory is already in `C:\Dir` you could shorten it further, in batch: `@For /D %%A In (*)Do @Copy "%%A"` or at the prompt: `For /D %A In (*)Do @Copy "%A"`. As you should be aware, the `Copy` command does not copy directories, only files, so simply giving it a directory name is sufficient to copy the files it contains.

Comment: AlexP, sorry for the comment deletion, I've rewritten it below your comment. It's inefficient, because if there's five subdirectories, each with ten files, you'll be running 50 copy commands, my examples would need only 5 copy commands!

Comment: @Compo: Copy is a builtin, and `copy *` still copies the files one by one...

Comment: @AlexP, semantics, but I didn't outright claim it was inefficient, I stated that it seems inefficient. Externally, you cannot envisage five nested for loops each with ten individual copy commands, to be as efficient as five direct copy commands, even if internally copy treats each file individually.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only the files you want to move then a quick a dirty method would be something like:

```
$InputFolder = "C:\Dir"

$FilesToMove = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $InputFolder -Recurse | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }
foreach ($File in $FilesToMove)
{
    Move-Item -LiteralPath $File.PSPath -Destination $InputFolder -Force
}
```

So if for example you have:
`C:\Dir\MyDir1\File.txt` it will move it to `c:\dir\file.txt`

However, no folders will be moved.

eg say `c:\Dir\MyDir2\AnotherDir\` contains `File1.txt` and `Fle2.txt` only the `.txt` files will get moved, `c:\Dir\MyDir2\AnotherDir\`  would remain intact but without any files.